# Hiding External Swf's in Adobe Air Applications

Tags: actionscript-3, air, actionscript-2

**Intro:**

I might be doing some work in air, and i had a quesiton.

**Question**

So lets say when im ready, i tell flash to include externalSwf.swf ( which contains premade as2 code, thus why its external ) when i package my air app.

**The Problem**

I noticed when i install the program, externalSwf.swf is in the programs directory in the program files folder. Is their a way to avoid this so someone cant just open up the folder and see what was included?

Comment: You can always embed externalSwf.swf as ByteArray in class and load bytes .